# How should I change an injected HTML element with variable using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, getelementbyid, html-injections

Question: What is the best practice to inject HTML, that contains javascript?

Script to load content in page:

```
elmnt = document.getElementById("contentcontainer");
elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;
```

Page:

```
Welcome to our restaurant!
<div id="contentcontainer"></div>
```

Responsetext:

```
<div>
The menu for today:
<script> Script to get API resonse menu(today); <script>
</div>
```

So I'm injecting HTML that contains a script. But the script is not executed. How should I change variable HTML inside an injection?

Comment: This code is confusing. You're putting the response in `maincontent`, but you have not defined a dom reference to accompany it.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is the best practice to inject html that contains variables?

Comment: You could inject the content, and THEN change the var of desired element

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/

Answer (score 0):

You could use "[Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)" and inject your already processed HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what the problem is. `InnerHtml` should work perfectly, as long as the variable is global and also you get the desire content.

Here is an example of what i understod off what you want.

```
let str = '<p><script>var test="this is a test"</script></p>'

document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].innerHTML  =str;

console.log(test) // and here is the injected script variable result
```

To get the content of the site from the url you will have to use a library like jq `getscript`
Did i understand you correctly?

Comment: No, sorry, this is not the needed answer. I tried to simplify my question. Hope that helps. Thank you!

Comment: Its exaktly what i showed you, The script will be executed after you add it to innerHTML and as long as the variable is global youcould change it.